# Tweeter search api asynchronous fetching of searched tweets

Tags: ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, twitter-search

Currently I am fetching tweets in my iphone application using tweeter search api.
Now my question is that how can I know that new tweets are tweeted by other users?And how can I fetch asynchronously newly available tweets?

**Explanation:**
As example in search api Url,I am searching about tweets of iPhone. So my URL will look like->   http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=iPhone

Now how can I know that anyone have posted new tweets about iPhone?And how can I parse it asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

Use the streaming API, it's not the same as the REST one you're using. Unsure when it was made, since this question is a bit old now. But it has what you are wanting